# What is the best practice for security with Restkit HTTPS or SSL?

Tags: ios, ssl, https, restkit

I am using restkit in my iOS project and not sure how to make network communication secure. If I use an https address, as opposed to http, is that good enough and will RestKit automatically know to encrypt data when I use an https URI?

Or do I need to setup a custom SSL? And how is that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Enough' is a relative term. You need to be very clear on what you're trying to protect against. Generally, HTTPS is enough.

HTTPS is does using SSL.

RestKit doesn't get involved in any encryption. The encryption is done by the URL loading system when you set the scheme to `https`.

Comment: But what about POSTing information up to the server from an iPhone? If someone sniffs it that can see what is passed without encrypting it first correct?

Comment: If you use http then it will be encrypted. It isn't easy to snif as you have to replace the DSL certificate...

Comment: Sorry, SSL, it does the actual certification / encryption.